# XP Practices Doubts

Tags: extreme-programming

I was doing some XP Multiple Choice Questions on [Sanfoundry](https://www.sanfoundry.com/software-engg-mcqs-extreme-programming/).

There are three answers I found confusing. (Note: **bold: system answer**, *italic: my answer*)

---

2. In XP, as soon as the work on a task is complete, it is integrated into the whole system. ****a) True**** *b) False*

Shouldn't any completed task be tested before and after it integrates into the whole system?

5. Is a customer involved test development and validation in XP ? *a) Yes* b) No **c) It may vary from Customer to Customer** d) None of the mentioned

One of XP practices is on-site customer where the customer is involved in all development cycles. Isn't test development and validation one of the cycles?

7. Tests are automated in Extreme Programming. **a) True** *b) False*

I agree tests can be automated. But it can be manual as well, right?

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shouldn't any completed task be tested before and after it integrates into the whole system?

Why would you call an untested task "completed"? Completed doesn't mean just developed (which I think is how you are looking at it). If something is completed then it means it was verified as working. Thus, it can be integrated in the rest of the application.

> One of XP practices is on-site customer where the customer is involved in all development cycles. Isn't test development and validation one of the cycles?

In XP, the customer should be present all throughout the development of the application to answer questions, set priorities, set goals, etc. But that doesn't make them a developer or tester. If they provided requirements and acceptance criteria and answered any of the development team's questions, then that's enough. Some clients get more involved in technical things, some less, so it depends.

> I agree tests can be automated. But it can be manual as well, right?

XP uses technical practices like Test-Driven Development (TDD). That means writing automated unit tests before writing application code. If you are doing XP with just manual testing, you are not really doing XP. Of course, some things need to be manually tested, like some human being looking at a graphical user interface and make sure it looks good, but the emphasis is on automating as much tests as possible.